# Subset a data frame by matching columns from another data frame

Tags: r

I've tried a number of ways to subset a data frame (IMD15) by matching against another dataframe or vector. I'm sure its something simple! I have been looking for hours before posting but I'm quite new to R I can't seem to find a soloution :(

```
## Import the English Indices of Deprivation 2015 - LSOA Level
IMD15 <- read.csv(url("https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/467774/File_7_ID_2015_All_ranks__deciles_and_scores_for_the_Indices_of_Deprivation__and_population_denominators.csv"))
LSOA2011 <- read.csv("LSOA2011.csv")
```

The LSOA2011.csv is 20 LSOA Codes (see below) I want to use to query the IMD15 Data.

> ("E01019602", "E01019614", "E01019615", "E01019631",  "E01019600",
>   "E01019604", "E01019606",
>                     "E01019618", "E01019599", "E01019601", "E01019613", "E01019617", "E01019632", "E01019635", 
>                     "E01019636", "E01019611", "E01019597", "E01019737", "E01029801", "E01029817")

```
## Format the column names
names(IMD15) [1] <- "LSOA code (2011)"
names(IMD15) [2] <- "LSOA name (2011)"
names(IMD15) [3] <- "Local Authority District code (2013)"
names(IMD15) [4] <- "Local Authority District name (2013)"
names(IMD15) [5] <- "Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Score"
names(IMD15) [6] <- "Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Rank (where 1 is most deprived)"
names(IMD15) [7] <- "Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Decile (where 1 is most deprived 10% of LSOAs)"

## Subset the data columns
IMD15 <- IMD15[ , 1:7] 


> str(IMD15)
'data.frame':   32844 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ LSOA code (2011)                                                                  : Factor w/ 32844 levels "E01000001","E01000002",..: 30557 30558 30559 30560 30578 30582 30546 30547 30548 30573 ...
 $ LSOA name (2011)                                                                  : Factor w/ 32844 levels "Adur 001A","Adur 001B",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Local Authority District code (2013)                                              : Factor w/ 326 levels "E06000001","E06000002",..: 241 241 241 241 241 241 241 241 241 241 ...
 $ Local Authority District name (2013)                                              : Factor w/ 326 levels "Adur","Allerdale",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Score                                         : num  12.4 28.6 11.7 16.4 18.3 ...
 $ Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Rank (where 1 is most deprived)               : int  21352 8864 22143 17252 15643 21176 27934 28249 27569 18352 ...
 $ Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Decile (where 1 is most deprived 10% of LSOAs): int  7 3 7 6 5 7 9 9 9 6 ...

> str(LSOA2011)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ LSOA2011: Factor w/ 20 levels "E01019597","E01019599",..: 5 10 11 14 3 6 7 13 2 4 ...
```

When I try method (a)

```
IMD15a <- IMD15[c("E01019602", "E01019614", "E01019615", "E01019631",   "E01019600", "E01019604", "E01019606",
             "E01019618", "E01019599", "E01019601", "E01019613", "E01019617", "E01019632", "E01019635", 
             "E01019636", "E01019611", "E01019597", "E01019737",    "E01029801", "E01029817"), ]
```

The results is NA values (20 obs of 7 variables)

```
> str(IMD15a)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ LSOA code (2011)                                                                  : Factor w/ 32844 levels "E01000001","E01000002",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ LSOA name (2011)                                                                  : Factor w/ 32844 levels "Adur 001A","Adur 001B",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Local Authority District code (2013)                                              : Factor w/ 326 levels "E06000001","E06000002",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Local Authority District name (2013)                                              : Factor w/ 326 levels "Adur","Allerdale",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Score                                         : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Rank (where 1 is most deprived)               : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Decile (where 1 is most deprived 10% of LSOAs): int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Or method (b)

```
IMD15b <- cbind(IMD15[match(names(LSOA2011), IMD15$`LSOA code (2011)` ),], LSOA2011)
```

This also results in NA values (20 obs of 8 variables)

```
> str(IMD15b)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ LSOA code (2011)                                                                  : Factor w/ 32844 levels "E01000001","E01000002",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ LSOA name (2011)                                                                  : Factor w/ 32844 levels "Adur 001A","Adur 001B",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Local Authority District code (2013)                                              : Factor w/ 326 levels "E06000001","E06000002",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Local Authority District name (2013)                                              : Factor w/ 326 levels "Adur","Allerdale",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Score                                         : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Rank (where 1 is most deprived)               : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Decile (where 1 is most deprived 10% of LSOAs): int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ LSOA2011                                                                          : Factor w/ 20 levels "E01019597","E01019599",..: 5 10 11 14 3 6 7 13 2 4 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
LSOA <- ("E01019602", "E01019614", "E01019615", "E01019631", "E01019600", "E01019604", "E01019606", "E01019618", "E01019599", "E01019601", "E01019613", "E01019617", "E01019632", "E01019635", "E01019636", "E01019611", "E01019597", "E01019737", "E01029801", "E01029817")

df <- IMD15[IMD15[['LSOA code (2011)']] %in% LSOA, ]

str(df)

'data.frame':   20 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ LSOA code (2011)                                                                  : Factor w/ 32844 levels "E01000001","E01000002",..: 19057 19069 19070 19086 19055 19059 19061 19073 19054 19056 ...
 $ LSOA name (2011)                                                                  : Factor w/ 32844 levels "Adur 001A","Adur 001B",..: 8566 8567 8568 8569 8570 8571 8572 8573 8574 8575 ...
 $ Local Authority District code (2013)                                              : Factor w/ 326 levels "E06000001","E06000002",..: 75 75 75 75 75 75 75 75 75 75 ...
 $ Local Authority District name (2013)                                              : Factor w/ 326 levels "Adur","Allerdale",..: 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 ...
 $ Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Score                                         : num  10.19 6.55 7.83 8.22 8.62 ...
 $ Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Rank (where 1 is most deprived)               : int  23963 28526 26942 26470 25943 30038 31052 24720 28159 20152 ...
 $ Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Decile (where 1 is most deprived 10% of LSOAs): int  8 9 9 9 8 10 10 8 9 7 ...
```